# How do i mention a member when they say a certain command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make the bot say "Hey (user) here is a download link for hxd" Can anyone help me?

```
async def hxd(ctx):
  await client.say('Here is a download link for hxd')
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `getpass.getuser()`:

```
from getpass import getuser
async def hxd(ctx):
  await client.say(f'Hey {getuser()} here is a download link for hxd')
```

Comment: I am getting this error: https://prnt.sc/tdeyik These are my imports: https://prnt.sc/tdez5m

Comment: @GrenadeVisuals Just `import getpass`, not `from os import getpass`

Comment: Why would you use `getpass` when you just have to use the `mention` attribute?

Comment: @Mr_Spaar Also, what wrong with the `getuser` attribute?

Comment: Since this question has a `discord.py` tag, he can use the `mention` attribute, so he just has to import only one library, which is `discord.py` ^^

Answer (score 2):

Every [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object has a [`mention`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=mention#discord.User.mention) attribute.
Here's how you use it:

```py
@client.command()
async def hxd(ctx):
  await client.say(f"Hey {ctx.author.mention}! Here's a download link for hxd")
```

Comment: You can use the slightly shorter ``ctx.author.mention`` too